# Sending image through mail from the external storage

Tags: android

I am not able to attach an image to the mail from external storage.
I tried to use this line.

`Uri image = Uri.parse("/storage/emulated/0/Pictures/park.jpg");`

In this case `mail` is showing a message like `can't attach empty file`.

After that i am trying to execute the following code. It is showing some crash report. I have gone through some previously asked questions on this. Still i am not able to find out the perfect answer.

Here is the code that i am using...

```
 Uri image = FileProvider.getUriForFile(this, "com.example.chint.asyntaskexample", new File("/storage/emulated/0/Pictures/", "park.jpg"));

    //Context
    //Package
    //File path (/storage/emulated/0/Pictures/park.jpg)

    Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, image);
    i.setType("image*//*");

    Intent chooser = Intent.createChooser(i, "Send Image");
    if (i.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null)
        startActivity(chooser);
    else
        Toast.makeText(this, "Nothing", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

I am getting a `crash` when i clicked on the `share` button.
Here is the `logcat`...

```
com.example.chint.asyntaskexample E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                             Process: com.example.chint.asyntaskexample, PID: 7157
                                                                             java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method for android:onClick
                                                                                 at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:293)
                                                                                 at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6256)
                                                                                 at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:24697)
                                                                                 at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:789)
                                                                                 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:98)
                                                                                 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6541)
                                                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                 at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240)
                                                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)
                                                                              Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
                                                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                 at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:288)
                                                                                 at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6256) 
                                                                                 at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:24697) 
                                                                                 at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:789) 
                                                                                 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:98) 
                                                                                 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164) 
                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6541) 
                                                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                                 at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240) 
                                                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767) 
                                                                              Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.res.XmlResourceParser android.content.pm.ProviderInfo.loadXmlMetaData(android.content.pm.PackageManager, java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
                                                                                 at android.support.v4.content.FileProvider.parsePathStrategy(FileProvider.java:583)
                                                                                 at android.support.v4.content.FileProvider.getPathStrategy(FileProvider.java:557)
                                                                                 at android.support.v4.content.FileProvider.getUriForFile(FileProvider.java:399)
                                                                                 at com.example.chint.asyntaskexample.MainActivity.sendImage(MainActivity.java:105)
                                                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                                 at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:288) 
                                                                                 at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6256) 
                                                                                 at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:24697) 
                                                                                 at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:789) 
                                                                                 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:98) 
                                                                                 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164) 
                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6541) 
                                                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                                 at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240) 
                                                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)
```

Please help me..

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the answer what i came up with...

```
String filePath = "/storage/emulated/0/Pictures/park.jpg";

            Bitmap screenShot = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filePath);
            File pic = new File(filePath);
            FileOutputStream out = null;
            try {
                out = new FileOutputStream(pic);
                screenShot.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, out);
                out.flush();
                out.close();
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(pic);

            Intent sendIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            sendIntent.setType("message/rfc822");
            sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri);
            Intent chooser = Intent.createChooser(sendIntent, "Send Image");

            if(sendIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null)
                startActivity(chooser);
            else
                Toast.makeText(ScreenShortAlertDialogue.this, "No Available Applications to send the image", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Uri image = Uri.parse("/storage/emulated/0/Pictures/park.jpg");
```

That is not a valid `Uri`, as it has no scheme. Also, do not hardcode paths. Beyond that, this will not work on Android 7.0+, as passing `file` `Uri` values has been banned.

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.res.XmlResourceParser android.content.pm.ProviderInfo.loadXmlMetaData(android.content.pm.PackageManager, java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
```

Apparently, you do not have a `<provider>` element for your `FileProvider` with an authority string of `com.example.chint.asyntaskexample`.

Also, `image*//*` is not a valid MIME type.